# How do I use react hooks in the code snippet

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

can we use react hooks in the code snippet
and how if yes
I tried this but not working

thanks for your answer

```js
import {useState} from 'react'

function Name({name, setName}){
  return <input type="text" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
}

function Hello({name}){
  return <p>Hi {name}, wassup ?</p>
}

function App(){

  const [name, setName] = useState('dude')
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Name name={name} setName={setName} />
      <Hello name={name} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its working fine for me.
You can refer to https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-field-pfjrj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for meta SO and possibly a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/691711

Comment: @saksh73 I know it should work in a basic react app but I'm just trying to run it on code snippet but doesnt work

Comment: zero298 your link got me to use this `const {useState} = React;` but was still so i changed the react version from 16 to 17 and now it's ok  thanks